# Programmatically change post templates?

Tags: templates

I need to change the template on several hundred pages on my site. Does anyone know if there is a command to do it programmatically? See the following code snippet; I'd like to replace my comment inside the loop with a function that will change the template of the current page:

```
query = new WP_Query($args);
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
  if ( has_tag('tag-slug') )
  {
     /* CHANGE TEMPLATE OF $post */
  }
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Watch out for the typo in your question. "$the_query->the_post" should be "$query->the_post".

Answer (score 4):

I take it that you mean saving the pages with a new post-template to the DB? see if there's anything in the post object that refers to the page-template, if so craft a query that updates that.

## Update:

> ### Taken from the [wp_insert_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) documentation
>
> NOTE: The page_template key was removed from the $post table and is
> now located in the wp_postmeta table. To set the page template of a
> page, use update_post_meta instead with a meta key of
> _wp_page_template.

So you can fetch the page template using [get_post_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta), and update it with [update_post_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) (Or set it with [add_post_meta](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta))

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm referring to. Do you know of a good source for documentation on the post object?

Comment: See updated answer :)

Answer (score 0):

What kinds of formatting are you referring to? If you want to change the formatting that can be changed by css. You can use [post_class()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class) which will add a class naming your tag in the container. Then you can style targeting that class.

Inside the loop:

```
<div <?php post_class()?> >
</div>
```

Also check the action [pre_get_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts); Using it with conditionals might help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
  if ( has_tag('tag-slug') )
  {
     get_template_part( 'content', 'tag-slug' );
  }
  else
  {
     get_template_part( 'content' );
  }

endwhile;
```

You would then need to create `content.php` and `content-tag-slug.php` with the appropriate content.

You could also look into setting up [Post Formats](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats). A bit more work up front, but a nicer experience down the road.

Answer (score 0):

To change the template of a post, call `update_post_meta($query->the_post->ID, '_wp_page_template', 'YOUR-NEW-TEMPLATE-HERE.php')`

Here, then, is the example from the WP Codex found in @Xeross's link with the code snippet from the original question:

```
$query = new WP_Query($args);
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
  if ( has_tag('tag-slug') )
  {
     /* CHANGE TEMPLATE OF $post */
    update_post_meta($query->the_post->ID, '_wp_page_template', 'YOUR-NEW-TEMPLATE-HERE.php');
  }
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Kudos to @Xeross for providing the answer in a link and providing the documentation about where the template datum is stored. See @Xeross's answer for more https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/24933/69247