# Programmatically change post templates?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wordpress - Programmatically change post templates?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24924/wordpress-programmatically-change-post-templates)

I need to change the template on several hundred pages on my site. Does anyone know if there is a command to do it programmatically? See the following code snippet; I'd like to replace my comment inside the loop with a function that will change the template of the current page:

```
query = new WP_Query($args);
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
  if ( has_tag('tag-slug') )
  {
     /* CHANGE TEMPLATE OF $post */
  }
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Watch out for the typo in your question. "$the_query->the_post" should be "$query->the_post".

Comment: Just noticed this question is a dup of http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24924/ I moved my answer over there and recommend this question be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
  if ( has_tag('tag-slug') )
  {
     get_template_part( 'content', 'tag-slug' );
  }
  else
  {
     get_template_part( 'content' );
  }

endwhile;
```

You would then need to create `content.php` and `content-tag-slug.php` with the appropriate content.

You could also look into setting up [Post Formats](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats). A bit more work up front, but a nicer experience down the road.